# How to trace line segments in a binary skeletonized image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a binarized and skeletonized image. I used Zhang-Suen algorithm for skeletonization. Now I need to get line segments from the image in a 2-point format (starting and ending point of the line segment).
So far I have been using OpenCV function *findContours*, with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE and CV_RETR_LIST options. However, three problems emerge:

1. This method returns duplicate line segments (in opposite direction)
2. Connected structures get sometimes disconnected due to the "hierarchy feature"
3. Messy results in the vicinity of lines' intersections.

Is there another way to trace the line segments from the image?

Magnified section of the image I need to trace:
[image: Magnified section of the image I need to trace]

Comment: You need start and end point for each 8-connected line? What about contours that have multiple path, like the lowest one?

Comment: Yes, what about them? I just need the coordinates of all straight and diagonal line segments.

Comment: So, consider for example the line on top. For you it's composed by a single line, or by two lines? i.e. by straight you mean on with the same y value?

Comment: The very first line on top? 3 segments. Two horizontal and one diagonal (with length of only two pixels).

Comment: ok, get it. If you post your original image I'll give it a shot

Comment: Ok sir, http://imgur.com/BOvU4t8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. It does 4 scan of the image (you can probably reduce the number of scans, but the logic would be more complicated).

In each scan, it tracks horizontal lines, vertical lines, diagonal towards down lines, and diagonal towards up lines.

Lines are stored in a `vector<Vec4i>`, where each `Vec4i` is a line with `Xstart, Ystart, Xend, Yend`;

Let me know if this works for you.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat1b w;
    // Add bg border
    copyMakeBorder(img, w, 1, 1, 1, 1, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    Vec4i line;

    // Scan horizontal lines 
    for (int y = 1; y < w.rows - 1; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < w.cols - 1; ++x)
        {
            if (w(y, x) == 255)
            {
                int yy = y;
                int xx = x;

                //Save first point
                line[0] = xx - 1;
                line[1] = yy - 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (w(yy, xx + 1))
                    {
                        // Mark as detected
                        w(yy, xx) = 1;
                        ++xx;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // End of the line
                        line[2] = xx - 1;
                        line[3] = yy - 1;

                        if (line[2] - line[0] > 0)
                        {
                            lines.push_back(line);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Scan vertical lines 
    for (int y = 1; y < w.rows - 1; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < w.cols - 1; ++x)
        {
            if (w(y, x) == 255)
            {
                int yy = y;
                int xx = x;

                //Save first point
                line[0] = xx - 1;
                line[1] = yy - 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (w(yy + 1, xx))
                    {
                        // Mark as detected
                        w(yy, xx) = 1;
                        ++yy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // End of the line
                        line[2] = xx - 1;
                        line[3] = yy - 1;

                        if (line[3] - line[1] > 0)
                        {
                            lines.push_back(line);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Scan for diagonal low lines 
    for (int y = 1; y < w.rows - 1; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < w.cols - 1; ++x)
        {
            if (w(y, x) == 255)
            {
                int yy = y;
                int xx = x;

                //Save first point
                line[0] = xx - 1;
                line[1] = yy - 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (w(yy + 1, xx + 1))
                    {
                        // Mark as detected
                        w(yy, xx) = 1;
                        ++xx;
                        ++yy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // End of the line
                        line[2] = xx - 1;
                        line[3] = yy - 1;
                        if (line[2] - line[0] > 0)
                        {
                            lines.push_back(line);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Scan for diagonal high lines 
    for (int y = 1; y < w.rows - 1; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < w.cols - 1; ++x)
        {
            if (w(y, x) == 255)
            {
                int yy = y;
                int xx = x;

                //Save first point
                line[0] = xx - 1;
                line[1] = yy - 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (w(yy - 1, xx + 1))
                    {
                        // Mark as detected
                        w(yy, xx) = 1;
                        ++xx;
                        --yy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // End of the line
                        line[2] = xx - 1;
                        line[3] = yy - 1;
                        if (line[2] - line[0] > 0)
                        {
                            lines.push_back(line);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    RNG rng(12345);
    Mat3b res;
    cvtColor(img, res, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
        const Vec4i& lin = lines[i];
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        cv::line(res, Point(lin[0], lin[1]), Point(lin[2], lin[3]), color);
    }

    imshow("res", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Starting from this image:

[image]

Drawing each detected line (from start to end) with random colors gives:

[image]

Zoomed:

[image]